# Google api returning wrong values

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, rjson

can you help me with extracting info from google API, when i supply address variable: 560066, 560065 (pincodes of bengaluru city), the address_components has different lengths (4 and 5 in this case)

This could return wrong data. Let say i wanted country info, following would return INDIA for former and 'error: out of bounds' for latter

Is there a universal way so that it returns country value for both case

```
library(rjson) # load rjson package

getCoordinates <- function(address) {
url <- paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",address,"&sensor=false",sep="")
map_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url),collapse=""))
coord <- c(map_data$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat,map_data$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng, toupper(map_data$results[[1]]$address_components[[5]]$long_name))
return(coord)
}

g <- getCoordinates(560066)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Google API you're not always guaranteed the same 'number' of results for each query, which is the issue you're describing.

What you need to extract is the `types : country` field, but to do this you need to know at what 'level' in the list the country field exists (if it does).

For this example I'm going to be using my `googleway` package to do the geocoding as it handles the construction of the API query for you

```
library(googleway)

## you need a valid Google API key to use their API
api_key <- "your_api_key"

query1 <- google_geocode(address = "560065", key = api_key)
query2 <- google_geocode(address = "560066", key = api_key)

## the 'country' is in the 'address_components : types' field
# query1$results$address_components

## use an 'lapply' to find the depth of the country field
l <- lapply(query2$results$address_components[[1]]$types, function(x){ 
    'country' %in% x
    })

## so now we know how far into the list we have to go
which(l == T)
# [1] 4

query2$results$address_components[[1]]$long_name[[which(l == T)]]
# [1] "India"
```

So wrapping this in a function:

```
getCountry <- function(g){

    l <- lapply(g[['results']][['address_components']][[1]][['types']], function(x){
        'country' %in% x
    })

    return(g[['results']][['address_components']][[1]][['long_name']][[which(l == T)]])
}

getCountry(query1)
# [1] "India"
getCountry(query2)
# [1] "India"
```

---

To incorporate this into your function you can do

```
getCoordinates <- function(address) {
    url <- paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",address,"&sensor=false",sep="")
    map_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url),collapse=""))

    l <- lapply(map_data$results[[1]]$address_components, function(x){
        'country' %in% x[['types']]
    })

    coord <- c(map_data$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat,map_data$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng, 
            toupper(map_data$results[[1]]$address_components[[which(l == T)]]$long_name))
    return(coord)
}

getCoordinates(560065)
[1] "12.9698066" "77.7499632" "INDIA"

getCoordinates(560066)
[1] "13.0935798" "77.5778529" "INDIA"
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a limit to it's use, After fixing this, i ran it on a list of 300+ city names, and it always stopped at 20 and threw an error, and now, even `g <- getCoordinates('AMSTERDAM')` won't work. Any idea? @SymbolixAU

Comment: @NemishKanwar There is a limit of 2500 requests per day. As for your error, I can't help without seeing it - maybe it's specific to your 20th entry? Either way, if you have a separate question you should open up a new question, rather than updating an already answered one.